# get address from public key with fastecdsa in python

Tags: python-3.x, ethereum, ecdsa

I generated key pairs in python using fastecdsa in Python:

```
from fastecdsa.keys import gen_keypair

private_key, public_key = gen_keypair(curve.secp256k1)
```

How can I generate an Ethereum like public address (last 20 bytes of public key)?

Thanks

Comment: This was helpful for me https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-an-ethereum-wallet-address-from-a-private-key-ae72b0eee27b/